# How do I make ANT verbose?

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

Trying to build my project with ANT in idea 10 and I get a compile error but I don't see the actual error.

How do I make ANT verbose?

All I see is:

```
javac build.xml:303: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for
details. at
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150)
etc.... rest of ANT stack trace
```

My task looks like this:

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" destdir="${webapp.classes.dir}" debug="true">
    <src path="${src.dir}"/>
    <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

Comment: [Maybe a dependency JAR missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667798/compile-failed-see-the-compiler-error-output-for-details)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To enable verbose output for ant:

```
ant -v
```

or

```
ant -verbose
```

Answer (score 22):

You can also enable logging on build.xml itself using task *record*. Here is documentation about it http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html

```
<record name="/output/build.log" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
```

It´s simple and works! :)

Comment: Note: If you get the error "Problems opening file using a recorder entry", this may simply mean that the folder you're trying to save your log file in doesn't exist yet.

Comment: It doesn't work for me even if I choose a file build.log with no prefix, i.e. in the root folder. I can the same error. Ant 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

There are also possibilities for subtler logging, means changing the noiselevel for specific parts only, not for the whole ant script as ant -v or ant -debug does. See  [Make ant quiet without the -q flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5462732/130683) for another question dealing with loglevel and answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the environment variable ANT_ARGS:

```
export ANT_ARGS="-verbose"
```

That applies even to ant builds executed via bash scripts.